# Is ist possible to install and use cool-retro-term wihtout a desktop?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I am kinda new to working with Ubuntu and want to play around a bit with web servers and such. I stumbled upon the Cool-Retro-term terminal (https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term) and was a bit amazed.

Yet I wish to use the Ubuntu installation without any desktop, to save resources.

Yet I would wish to use the Retro Terminal. Is it possible to install only the parts that would make up the Terminal emulator to use this as your default input device?

Comment: `cool-retro-term` uses Qt (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/cool-retro-term) so it'll require a fair amount of Qt to be running to use it (ie. it was written to work on a GUI desktop) so it wouldn't be efficient use of resources just for a 'cool' interface..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bit of understanding on what happens where.

Traditionally Unix has used the concept of command line interpreters ("shells") running in terminal (typically multiple devices attached using a serial cable or modems, so that Unix itself just reads characters as input, process them and send characters back to the user.  The X11 system is an appendix to Unix which happens to give a graphical user interface supporting a mouse and bitmaps and all.

Linux essentially is the same, except that today serial connections are emulated using the `ssh` command allowing you to run commands on another computer remotely over the network.

This means that unless you have a graphical frontend there is simply no place to give what you see on the screen dumps on the github page.  You can run an ssh connection to your machine and it is up to the terminal emulator that ssh runs in to render what you see.  This is typically rather boring.

As you are learning I would strongly suggest that you for now simply just install the default Ubuntu desktop and this terminal emulator as well, and play with it.  Then reinstall when you are more familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I did dable with it and found a solution suitable for me. Might not be as efficient but for test out stuff its cool for me!

Comment: @Shinji_Shinigami And your solution was?  Just in case this might interest others....

Comment: Ah, i installed the normal desktop enviorment, used auto login and autostart so i the retro Terminal came up right at the start. with the parameters "-- fullscreen" and "--profile" i could have it load like wanted it. Though like i said, ressource friendly is something else. But it gave the optical effect i disired